# How to build dummy panel in R?

Tags: r

How do I generate a dummy variable which is zero before `year` and takes the value 1 from `year` and onwards to 2019?
Original data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Year = c(2017, 
2015, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

what I need:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Year = c(2017, 
2015, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), `2015` = c(NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2016` = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `2017` = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2018` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `2019` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Make your input reproducible, `dput(myData)`.

Comment: how to copy data from excel

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

*split* on id, extend year range `i:2019`, then *reshape* from long-to-wide:

```
res <- reshape(stack(sapply(split(df2$Year, df2$id), function(i) i:2019)),
               timevar = "values", v.names = "values", idvar = "ind", 
               direction = "wide")

# fix the column names order
res <- res[ sort(colnames(res)) ]

res
#    ind values.2015 values.2016 values.2017 values.2018 values.2019
# 1    1          NA          NA        2017        2018        2019
# 4    2        2015        2016        2017        2018        2019
# 9    3          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
# 11   4          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
# 13   5          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
# 15   6          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
# 17   7          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
# 19   8          NA          NA          NA        2018        2019
```